# equals and hashcode - Justify Contract

Tags: java

If two objects are equal then they should have the same hascode but the reverse is not true (i.e. If two objects have the same hashcode does not mean that they are equal) -- Can you please justify it using an example? Thanks

Comment: @bunny: In fairness, he may just be trying to understand what hashCodes are for and how they work.

Comment: As least ask the question in your own wording.

Answer (score 8):

Easy: how many possible strings are there? Now how many possible hash code values are there? How else would you propose handling this problem?

Basically, hash codes are meant to be a way of quickly getting to a *possible* match, so that you can narrow down the field of candidates extremely quickly. The fact that they *don't* have to be unique means that they can contain less information than the original data.

Comment: @user358099: Did you consider the answers to the first two questions? The idea is to get you to *think* about this...

Comment: This is known as the [PigeonHole Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle)

Comment: @Brian: Indeed - I didn't want to link to it originally, as it would give away the answers to those questions instead of the OP thinking about it first :)

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question "How many strings are there?" read Borges' "Library of Babel", (http://jubal.westnet.com/hyperdiscordia/library_of_babel.html).

To answer the question "How many possible Hash Codes are there?" look in your Java documentation for the type returned by `Object.hashCode()` and then determine how many possible values that type can have.

Comment: Hey, this reminds me of a tangent: Years ago I saw an ad for some file compression software that said that they GUARANTEED that it would reduce the size of any file by at least 50%. A few minutes thought will show that that is impossible. Consider the set of all 2-byte files. If this claim is true, then they must be able to reduce all these files to 1 byte. How many possible 2-byte files are there? How many possible 1-byte files are there? Well, I'm assuming that a compressed file can be decompressed to regain the original contents. If not, it's kind of useless.

Comment: @Jay The claim also implies that successive applications of the compression would reduce any file to one byte. A slight loss of entropy ;-)

Comment: Then you apply the algorithm again to the one-byte file.  :D

Comment: @EJP: Good point! So if we put all the data in the world into one big ZIP file, and then repeatedly run this compression algorithm, we could ultimately reduce it all to 1 byte! Then if you could just memorize that one byte, you'd have all the world's knowledge in your head!